# Mariadb Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: sql, mariadb

Hey I am using the following mariadb code to create a table called user with some foreign keys

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `shipping_address` int(11) NULL,
  ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `billing_address` int(11) NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS `user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_address`) REFERENCES `user_address` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS `user_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`billing_address`) REFERENCES `user_address` (`id`);
```

I think that this code is correct but still it generates the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (`shipping_address`) REFERENCES `user_address` (`id`),
  ADD CON...' at line
```

Is this code actually correct? If not then how do I fix it? What would be the correct varient of this code? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am testing this code on phpmyadmin

Regards.

Comment: You are using mariadb, not mysql. Mysql does not support the if not exists clause in alter table at all, so your question is applicable to mariadb only.

Comment: I don't believe MariaDB supports the IF NOT EXISTS clause on ADD CONSTRAINT.  It does on ADD COLUMN.

Comment: @Shadow well I tried that code in phpmyadmin which does use mysql by default if I am not wrong but still the same error.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes but by default on phpmyadmin there's mysql am I right? and considering the fact that I tested this code on phpmyadmin as well still gives the error makes me think that the error is something else while the error itself says that it's mariaDB I am so confused here any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan which would be totally expected as mysql does not support the if not exists clause at all in alter table statements. Although you are wrong to assume that phpmyadmin connects to mysql as default.

Comment: @Shadow hmm so is there a way to make this code work with mysql? like what changes can I do with it?

Comment: You are using mariadb, not mysql.

Comment: @Shadow I mean yes is there a way to make it work with mariadb? '0-0 sorry I am not an expert at databases so don't mind if I sound annoying which I realize that I do.

Comment: You can remove the "IF NOT EXISTS" clauses and just not run this when the constraints already exist.  No big deal

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok I'll try that thanks for all the help, and sorry for being annoying '0-0 :) you know I am a beginner.

Comment: You just placed the if not exists clause to the wrong part of the code. Checking out documentation for syntax errors should always be your first point! Btw, many people think that mariadb is the same as mysql. No, it is not. It is a **fork** of mysql, with increasingly bigger differences between the two. Many questions and answers are applicable to both. This one is not.

Comment: @Shadow I see thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mariadb (not mysql!) documentation on [alter table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) shows, the `if not exists` clause comes **after** `foreign key`:

```
ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
    FOREIGN KEY [IF NOT EXISTS] [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
    reference_definition
```

So, your alter table should look something like

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `shipping_address` int(11) NULL,
  ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `billing_address` int(11) NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS (`shipping_address`) REFERENCES `user_address` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS (`billing_address`) REFERENCES `user_address` (`id`);
```

Comment: Ohk I'll try that then.